# Integration by parts when only the definite integral is known

Tags: calculus

I have

$$ \int\limits_a^b v' dx = A  $$

$$ \int u'dx = u $$

That is I have the definite integral of $v'$ and the indefinite integral of $u'$. $v$ is unknown.

I want to evaluate by integration by parts:

$$ \int\limits_a^b u v'dx = ? $$

Comment: This will not be possible in general.